# How to switch between just 2 keyboard languages on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, language

I currently have 3 keyboard languages in use, but I regularly use just 2 of them. I'm finding a way to switch between only 2 languages without a 3rd party software or a dedicated shortcut for each language.

On Windows 7 you can click 'show more' when adding keyboard layout to show layouts from other languages. I can mimic the behavior I wanted by having the first and second language layout under a single keyboard language then use the layout-switch shortcut to switch between the two and leave the 3rd language as the second keyboard.

On Windows 10 the 'show more' button seems to have disappeared and you can only add additional layout of the same languages only. Is there an alternative workaround?

Comment: Do you know about Win+Space? It cycles through all installed keyboards but it is very quick and easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to switch only between two keyboard layouts.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 11 you can run the following command in a PowerShell (as admin):

```
Set-WinUserLanguageList en-US, es-US
```

Replace `en-US, es-US` with the list of language code you want to have.